# Connecting to customer site with Citrix XenApp

Tags: citrix, xenapp

Whenever I connect to customer site with Citrix Xenapp it takes me around 15-20 minutes for the Remote Desktop Prompt to come up, while for other users it's almost immediate. My connection is faster than theirs(25/4mbps). What is Citrix XenApp doing that's taking mine so long- any guesses?

The IT person at the customer site, said it's because my profile is over 1gb. What is "my profile"? They haven't been able to tell me that. They said I should "clear stuff off my desktop". Whenever I clear my things off the desktop at the customer site, it comes back the next time I login - like undeletes. Are they talking about desktop on their server, or on my local machine?

Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

The profile being referred to is your Windows Roaming Profile. The most esstenial part of the roaming profile is ntuser.dat, which contains registry information for that user. It also can contain a large amount of data stored in system folders such as the Desktop or My Documents if folder redirection is not enabled.

So what happens when you try and open RDP from the XenApp server is that server requests your roaming profile from another server on the backend and downloads a local copy to the XenApp server. The profile is not sent to your local computer. The beauty of XenApp is that you only see compressed screen updates. So if the XenApp farm is well designed, your roaming profile is on a LAN server on the backend so the roaming profile can be accessed very fast.

Comment: Roaming profiles *can* be fast. But a profile > 1GB (!) is huge. I'd guess the Xen server is resource-limited and it just takes time to assemble that big a profile with the overlays that it does.